# Adding to a ASP.NET user control constructor

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I've created an asp.net user control and I am trying to add logic to the user control's constructor. When I added the constructor to the user control I received an error telling me there were duplicate constructors. I'm assuming asp.net is creating one for me and then creating mine separately. How do I add logic to my User control constructor?

Answer (score 2):

Try overloading the constructor....